# How to get procedural shader to deform with bone deformation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rigging, shaders, procedural

I'm using a procedural shader (Cycles) on a model that I've rigged for animation.

When I pose the bones, the texture seems to be projected based on the world space and doesn't move with the deformation.

I saw someone fix this in a YT video a while ago, but now I can't find it.

Comment: To move with the surface, the shader would either have to be a function of, or baked  into, UV space.

Comment: If you don't need it to be animated you can either bake the colour in the cycles render settings. Or you can set it to be UV with a texture coordinate node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you UV-unwrap your model and use the UV coordinates as "Vector" input for your procedurals, you should be fine independent of deformation.
You will probably need to readjust the scale of some of the procedural textures after using a different set of input coordinates, though.
[image]